# XCTest cannot access an error message label on the screen

Tags: ios, xcode8, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

#### **Background info:**

I need to write some UI tests for simple app screen which has a navigation bar at the top and a table with two cells on the rest of the screen.

Each cell contains:

- a label ("Loyalty card number")
- a secure text field for the input
- a label under the secure field ("This is where you must put your
  10-digit loyalty card number")
- an optional error text which appears under the input field only when
  the user puts less or more than the number of the required digits

This is an image which gives an idea of the elements on the screen
[image]

#### **Goal:**

Write a test doing the following:

- tap on the card input field
- type an invalid card number (let's say, 12 digits instead of 10)
- check whether an error message appeared under the field

#### **Issue:**

XCTest is unable to identify the element containing the error.

When I inspect the element with Debug View Hierarchy, it is there, clearly visible, with text property "Cannot be less or more than 10 digits", with accessibiltyIndentifier "errorField".

Hierachy: UIWindow->UILayoutContainerView->UINavigationTransitionView->UIViewControllerWrapperView->UIView->Form->FormTextFieldCell->UITableViewCellContentView->UIView->UILabel

It has a sibling, also UILabel ("This is where you must put your 10-digit loyalty card") - and there is no problem with accessing this sibling. I can access it either by accessibilityIdentifier or by its text:

```
app.staticTexts["hintField"]
app.staticTexts["This is where you must put your 10-digit loyalty card"]
```

None of these options works for the element I'm interested in though. When I print app.debugDescription, the element is just not there as if it didn't exist.

Here is the output of the debugDescription after the user has made erroneous input and the error text is already visible on the screen:

```
Element subtree:
 →Application 0x60000016e700: {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: ‘test-app’
Window 0x60000016e7c0: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
  Other 0x60000016e4c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
    NavigationBar 0x60000016e580: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 44.0}}, identifier: ‘Card Info Screen’
      Button 0x60000016e880: traits: 8589934593, {{20.0, 26.7}, {53.0, 30.0}}, label: ‘Back’
      StaticText 0x60000016eac0: traits: 8590000192, {{158.7, 28.0}, {97.0, 27.0}}, label: ‘Next’
      Button 0x60000016ea00: traits: 8589934849, {{356.0, 26.7}, {38.0, 30.0}}, label: ‘Next’
    Other 0x60000016e940: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Other 0x60000016ed00: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
        Other 0x60000016edc0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 672.0}}
          Other 0x60000016ee80: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 48.0}}
            StaticText 0x60000016eb80: traits: 8589934656, {{24.0, 79.0}, {366.0, 18.0}}, label: ‘Enter your loyalty card information.’
          Table 0x60000016ef40: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 112.0}, {414.0, 573.0}}
            Cell 0x60000016ec40: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 112.0}, {414.0, 67.0}}
              StaticText 0x60000016f000: traits: 8589934656, {{16.0, 123.3}, {96.3, 18.0}}, label: ‘Your loyalty card nr’
              StaticText 0x60000016f0c0: traits: 8589934656, {{16.0, 158.7}, {390.0, 13.7}}, identifier: ‘hintField’, label: ‘This is where you must put your 10-digit loyalty card.’
              SecureTextField 0x60000016f180: traits: 8609071104, Keyboard Focused, {{119.3, 122.0}, {286.7, 20.0}}, identifier: ‘editField’, value: ••••••••••••
            Cell 0x60000016f240: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 179.0}, {414.0, 53.0}}
              StaticText 0x60000016f300: traits: 8589934656, {{16.0, 189.0}, {100.7, 18.0}}, label: ‘Birthday’
              StaticText 0x60000016f3c0: traits: 8589934656, {{16.0, 210.0}, {390.0, 13.7}}, identifier: ‘hintField’, label: ‘Please enter your birthday in DDMMYYYY format’
              SecureTextField 0x60000016f480: traits: 8606973952, {{123.7, 189.0}, {282.3, 18.0}}, identifier: ‘editField’, placeholderValue: ‘********’
            Cell 0x60000016f540: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 232.0}, {414.0, 70.0}}
          Other 0x60000016f600: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 685.0}, {414.0, 51.0}}
            StaticText 0x60000016f6c0: traits: 8589934656, {{112.0, 685.0}, {190.0, 15.7}}, label: ‘Don't have a loyalty card yet?’
            Button 0x60000016f780: traits: 8589934593, {{162.7, 705.7}, {90.0, 22.3}}, label: ‘Get one in one of our stores!’
```

When I  tried using Test Recorder, interacting with the error in any way leads to:
"Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element".

I should note that Test Recorder doesn't have this problem with any other elements on the screen. The only element that he cannot record tapping on is the error message. He cannot do this for the first cell with the loyalty card, and he also cannot do it for the second cell with a birthday.

I tried accessing this elusive element by:

```
app.staticTexts["ACCESSIBILITY_ID"]
app.staticTexts["ELEMENTS_TEXT]
app.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier: "ACCESSIBILITY_ID_OF_PARENT").otherElements.element
```

Unfortunately, nothing worked so far.

I'm blocked with other tests and getting seriously desperate.

Any help, any kind of advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Judging by the screenshot, your app is written using some sort of hybrid framework? It's possible the test view hierarchy hasn't updated correctly if the error label appears without animation. What happens if you make the error message appear and then tap on something else on the screen, then search for it again?

Comment: Do you have control over the UI? And if so, have you tried creating another label that is a copy of the one you can access?

Comment: I did try to make XCTest click on the screen (no problems with that, the click was successful) and then try to print debugDescription + find the element. I had exactly the same thought - maybe some kind of "refresh" is needed to make it see the updated hierachy. Unfortunately, that didn't work - XCTest cannot find the element and debugDescription shows exactly the same hierachy as before tapping elsewhere on the screen :(

Comment: N Brown: I'm a tester, so I'm not allowed to make any changes in the code, except for adding accessibilityIdentificator value to elements.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to check is whether or not the Accessibility framework can see the element. To see what accessibility sees, launch your app and open the accessibility inspector by going to

```
Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Accessibility Inspector
```

Then, select the Simulator under the target list at the top left, and select the target reticle at the top right. Hover over the label you want to check. This will show you the accessibility values and labels (and in Xcode 9, the identifier, as well). If the accessibility inspector can't see it, there is a problem with how the label is set in code, and it means Voice Over users won't have it read to them, either.

---

Since your existing XCUITest hierarchy shows the contents of the UITableViewCell, we can likely rule out the cell being a discrete accessibility element (which would hide subviews from XCUITest / accessibility. You could check that the cell is *not* marked as an accessibility element, though. The UIView flag for that is `isAccessibilityElement = true`. You could also check if your developers set this to true and then set accessible subviews:

```
myCell.accessibilityElements = [inputTextField, label1, label2] // left out error label, hence it's not accessible
```

If you're concerned that the hierarchy might not be getting refreshed, you could try telling it to refresh after your error view appears via:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, myErrorLabel);
```

Which also switch accessibility focus to that error when it appears. (More on posting accessibility notifications here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility)

Comment: Refreshing also didn't help, although I'm really thankful for this suggestion - it will come in handy for my other tests for sure. I've also looked through the code, and as it was a bit hard for me to read (written in Objective-C), so I've asked a developer to help me. He said the code pertaining to that particular field does not mention accessibility at all, anywhere. Unfortunately, he couldn't find any reason as to why the cursed error label is not seen by XCTest :(

Comment: Accessibility Inspector saw the element as a whole, with Label = <nil>, Title = <nil>, Value = Loyalty card nr, Cannot be less or more than 10 digits, This is where you must put your 10-digit card nr, Type = text. I tried to change the way I'm searching for an element to include a predicate: let element = app.staticTexts.element(matching: NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'Cannot') - unfortunately, that didn't help and the test still failed at the point where it was trying to find the error.

Comment: If it's seeing the element as a whole, that means it can't see each individual element (and each individual element). Likely the cell is set as the accessibility element. You should probably break apart the cell so accessibility can interact with the elements.

```cell.isAccessibilityElement = false```

Comment: I've set the cell accessibility to false, unfortunately, the error message is still not seen by the framework. Weirdly enough, all other parts of the cell are seen without any problems and can be located. Just not this one. I think I'll have to give up on trying to test if the error appears or not.